# SQL Query - 3 Tables - Table 1 joins to table 2, table 2 joins to table 3, all to get id from table 3 to fit nicely in table 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have a question which is somewhat difficult to put into words, though I hope using a desired output will help to clarify what I am asking.

I have three tables.  First table contains CustomerIDs and names:

```
CREATE TABLE #CustomerTable1 
(
    CustomerID VARCHAR(25), 
    CustomerName VARCHAR(25)
) 

INSERT INTO #CustomerTable1 
VALUES ('0156', 'Frank'), ('0178', 'Darrull'), 
       ('0908', 'Mary'), ('0785', 'Bertha')

CustomerID  CustomerName
-------------------------
0156        Frank
0178        Darrull
0908        Mary
0785        Bertha
```

Second table contains the `CustomerID` from table 1, a `LineNBR` column, and what I call an `ArbitraryID`. A customer can only have one `ArbitraryID`, but several `LineNBRs`:

```
CREATE TABLE #CustomerTable2 
(
    CustomerIDFromTable1 varchar(25), 
    LineNBR VARCHAR(25), 
    ArbitraryID VARCHAR(25)
)

INSERT INTO #CustomerTable2 
VALUES ('0156', '1', '167483'), ('0156', '2', NULL), 
       ('0156', '3', NULL), ('0156', '4', NULL),
       ('0178', '1', NULL), ('0178', '2', '873923'), 
       ('0178', '3', NULL), ('0178', '4', NULL),
       ('0908', '1', NULL), ('0908', '2', NULL), 
       ('0908', '2', NULL), ('0908', '4', NULL),
       ('0785', '1', NULL), ('0785', '2', NULL),
       ('0785', '3', NULL), ('0785', '4', NULL)


CustomerIDFromTable1    LineNBR ArbitraryID
-------------------------------------------
0156                    1       167483
0156                    2       NULL
0156                    3       NULL
0156                    4       NULL
0178                    1       NULL
0178                    2       873923
0178                    3       NULL
0178                    4       NULL
0908                    1       NULL
0908                    2       NULL
0908                    3       NULL
0908                    4       NULL
0785                    1       NULL
0785                    2       NULL
0785                    3       NULL
0785                    4       NULL
```

Third table contains any `ArbitraryID` from table 2 and an additional `ID` that I label `OtherID`.  There can only be one `OtherID` per `ArbitraryID`:

```
CREATE TABLE #CustomerTable3 
(
    ArbitraryIDFromTable2 VARCHAR(25), 
    OtherID VARCHAR(25)
)

INSERT INTO #CustomerTable3 
VALUES ('167483', '89987648'), ('873923', '45564783')

ArbitraryIDFromTable2   OtherID
---------------------------------
167483                  89987648
873923                  45564783
```

My question is this:

How do I join these three tables to make sure to get the OtherID, where it exists, for the CustomerIDs that have an a non-null ArbitraryID in table 2?

The results should look like this:

```
CustomerID      CustomerName    OtherIDFromTable3
--------------------------------------------------
0156            Frank           89987648
0178            Darrull         873923
0908            Mary            NULL
0785            Bertha          NULL
```

I've started with this, but am getting duplicates, of course:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    a.CustomerID AS CustomerIDFinal,
    a.CustomerName,
    c.OtherID
FROM
    #CustomerTable1 a
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    #CustomerTable2 b ON a.CustomerID = b.CustomerIDFromTable1
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    #CustomerTable3 c ON c.ArbitraryIDFromTable2 = b.ArbitraryID
```

EDIT!
Just out of curiosity, wondering if someone can solve with an updated version of #CustomerTable2

```
CREATE TABLE #CustomerTable2 
( CustomerIDFromTable1 varchar(25), 
  LineNBR VARCHAR(25), 
  ArbitraryID VARCHAR(25))

INSERT INTO #CustomerTable2 VALUES
('0156', '1', '167483'), ('0156', '2', '167483'), 
('0156', '3', '167483'), ('0156', '4', '167483'),
('0178', '1', '873923'), ('0178', '2', '873923'), 
('0178', '3', '873923'), ('0178', '4', NULL),
('0908', '1', NULL), ('0908', '2', NULL), 
('0908', '2', NULL), ('0908', '4', NULL),
('0785', '1', NULL), ('0785', '2', NULL), 
('0785', '3', NULL), ('0785', '4', NULL)
```

Comment: @Kendle Not sure I understand what you are asking.  Based on the example I provided, the `OtherID` relates to the `CustomerID` through the `ArbitraryID`

Answer (score 2):

If you don't actually need the join (and just want the column from table 3), one way of doing it would be to just put a subquery for that column:

```
SELECT
    a.CustomerID AS CustomerIDFinal
    ,a.CustomerName
    ,(SELECT c.OtherId FROM #CustomerTable3 c INNER JOIN #CustomerTable2 b ON c.ArbitraryIDFromTable2 = b.ArbitraryID WHERE a.CustomerID = b.CustomerIDFromTable1) OtherId
FROM #CustomerTable1 a
```

With a join, you probably want something like:

```
SELECT
    a.CustomerID AS CustomerIDFinal
    ,a.CustomerName
    ,d.OtherID
FROM #CustomerTable1 a
 LEFT OUTER JOIN 
 (
  SELECT c.OtherId, b.CustomerIDFromTable1 
  FROM #CustomerTable3 c INNER JOIN #CustomerTable2 b
   ON c.ArbitraryIDFromTable2 = b.ArbitraryID
 ) d
  ON a.CustomerID = d.CustomerIDFromTable1
```

This is the same idea. You use an `inner join` between table 2 and 3 (eliminates the "duplicates" you see, but use a `left join` with table 1 because not every record in table 1 matches a record in table 3.

Here is a [fiddle of it](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e641bdb3cfa8417cb2ed2097d9f936cb) giving your desired output.

**Added for the updated question:** You don't say which value you want if there are multiple matches, but if you don't care, you care use `MAX` like:

```
SELECT
    a.CustomerID AS CustomerIDFinal
    ,a.CustomerName
    ,(SELECT max(c.OtherId) FROM #CustomerTable3 c INNER JOIN
    #CustomerTable2 b ON c.ArbitraryIDFromTable2 = b.ArbitraryID WHERE a.CustomerID = b.CustomerIDFromTable1) OtherId
FROM #CustomerTable1 a
```

If the particular row you care about matters, you can use an aggregate function other than `max` or you can incorporate a `row_number() OVER (ORDER BY line_nr)` clause (or something of that nature).

Comment: That works wonderfully.  Thank you for this!  Wish I had your brain.

Comment: This is also a case where right join can be handy. B inner join C right join A

Comment: @EdmCoff Are you able to solve with the updated version of table at the end of the original post?

Comment: @EthanT you should not change your question/problem like that. If you have an answer to your original question. you should have accepted an answer as correct and created a new post for the new problem. Provide a link to the old question if you want to.

Comment: @DhruvJoshi - The answer to the original question is still applicable.  The change to the question to see if it can be solved with an updated table is only a curiosity.

Comment: @EthanT Alright, I added a possible solution for that with an explanation. I hope that helps. Please accept the answer if it did.

Answer (score 0):

When you create table second and third table, you should include FOREIGN KEY, so they can connect. Try alter your table and add FOREIGN KEY.

```
ALTER TABLE Orders
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (PersonID) REFERENCES Persons(PersonID);
```

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp

Comment: ALTER TABLE Orders
ADD FOREIGN KEY (PersonID) REFERENCES Persons(PersonID);

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp

Comment: Foreign keys are helpful, but in the case of temp tables, I'm not sure of how much good they will do.

Comment: The "#" for the table is the indicator of a TEMPORARY table per connected session, not a permanent table of the database.  As soon as session query is complete, the table is temp table is destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a Cartesian result/product as a result of your line number table (Table2) where there are more entries per customer.  Basically, what you need to do is a LEFT JOIN to table2 by ID AND NOT NULL of the Abritrary ID, then left-join continues to the third table.

```
select DISTINCT
      t1.CustomerID,
      t1.CustomerName,
      t3.OtherID
   from
      #CustomerTable1 t1
         LEFT JOIN #CustomerTable2 t2
            on t1.CustomerID = t2.CustomerIDFromTable1
            AND NOT t2.ArbitraryID IS NULL
            LEFT JOIN #CustomerTable3 t3
               on t2.ArbitraryID = t3.ArbitraryIDFromTable2
```

Since your rule indicates that table 2 can only have ONE instance of an ArbitraryID per customer, adding the

```
AND NOT t2.ArbitraryID IS NULL
```

means I only want to see those that DO have the Arbitrary ID.  Which is then finally joined to table 3 for its final OtherID value

REVISION based on comment.  I was adding the line number even though it was not explicitly asked for just to show how the context of which record qualified the join.

To qualify similar results, you changed your rule that the second table would only have ONE entry with an arbitrary ID, but your NEW sample data has multiple rows for a single customer having the SAME abitrary ID.  TO handle, I removed the LineNBR column and just added DISTINCT.  Distinct prevents duplicates of whatever returned columns, thus ignoring the extra lines per customer that had the arbitrary ID assigned.

Comment: thank you for your answer! Are you able to solve with the updated version of table at the end of the original post?

Comment: @EthanT, see revised answer and switch to DISTINCT and removed the LineNBR column.